# Insert datatable into a database table from a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net, datatable

I have a datatable with some rows I need to insert that datatable in to database using a stored procedure.

```
 For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@DOWNLOAD_ID", dt.Rows(0)("DOWNLOAD_ID").ToString()))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@FINALY_FIELDCODE", dt.Rows(0)("FINALY_FIELDCODE").ToString().Replace("|", "").ToString()))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@UNITS", dt.Rows(0)("UNITS").ToString()))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@CURRECY_CODE", dt.Rows(0)("CURRENCY_CODE").ToString()))
        Next
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When i do this I got an exception `{"Parameter '@DOWNLOAD_ID' has already been defined."}` How to get rid of this exception and can we insert the datatable with out for loop. 
Can any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create separate MySqlCommands and execute them directly:

```
Using mysqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    mysqlConnection.Open()
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Using cmd = New MySqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", mysqlConnection)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@DOWNLOAD_ID", dt.Rows(0)("DOWNLOAD_ID").ToString()))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@FINALY_FIELDCODE", dt.Rows(0)("FINALY_FIELDCODE").ToString().Replace("|", "").ToString()))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@UNITS", dt.Rows(0)("UNITS").ToString()))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@CURRECY_CODE", dt.Rows(0)("CURRENCY_CODE").ToString()))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: :hi.. thanks its working. but download_id and finaly_fieldcode are primary keys. i can insert a record manualy using a query of same download_id. i couldnt insert it from stored procedure